# Enumerate in 'for' function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, enumerate

I want to add a column named `X` in every `.tsv` file. I want this column to have the value of the corresponding index in the `folder_names` list (one value of the `folder_names` per .tsv file). But the `enumerate` function repeat itself in each iteration of the `for loop`, so the column 'X' always get the last value of `names` instead of the corresponding one.

I got these two lists:

`all_files_tsv = [tsv_file_1, tsv_file_2.... tsv_file_n]`

`folder_names = [folder_name_1, folder_name_2.... folder_name_n]`

And the output desired is the following:

`tsv_file_1`:

| Column1 | Column2 | X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | folder_name_1 |
| 2 | B | folder_name_1 |
| 3 | C | folder_name_1 |

`tsv_file_2`:

| Column1 | Column2 | X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | --- | folder_name_2 |
| 2 | --- | folder_name_2 |
| 3 | --- | folder_name_2 |

And this is the code that I have right now:

```
for file_ in all_files_tsv:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,sep = '\t', header=0)
    for index, names in enumerate(folder_names):
        df['X'] = names
```

Any idea of how could I solve this?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with pandas, but do you maybe want to do something like `df['X'][index] = names`?  Or maybe the other way around?

Comment: Is `folder_names` a normal list and do you want all columns to have the same values?

Comment: You're not using `index`, so why are you using `enumerate()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `enumerate()`. You can iterate over `all_files_tsv` and `folder_names` in parallel using `zip()` to get corresponding elements.

```
for file, name in zip(all_files_tsv, folder_names):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header=0)
    df['X'] = name
    df.to_csv(file, sep='\t', header=0)
```

Nested loops are used when you want a cross product between two lists, `zip()` is used when you want to pair corresponding elements.

Comment: I was writing an answer but this is better. It seems the OP is new, so for the sake of completeness, allow me to add that this is equivalent to `for index, file_ in enumerate(all_files_tsv): df = pd.read_csv(file_,sep = '\t', header=0); df['X'] = folder_names[index]`.

Comment: Right, he was enumerating the wrong list.